# How to create SVG on a specific div rather than entire body using D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working on a project which gets a text from user either from a textbox or from a text file and calculates the frequency of alphabets. The code works fine upon submitting the text, rather than updating a div, D3 updates the entire body.

HTML code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="frequencyCalc.js"></script>
    <title>TAFC</title>
    <body>
    <h1 align="center">Text Alphabet Frequency Calculator </h1>
    <p align="center"> calculates the frequency of each alphabet character entered </p>
    <div id="input" align="left">
    </br>
    <h2>Enter Some Text here</h2>
    <form>
    <textarea id="myTextBox" cols="60" rows="20" style="background-color:#FCF5D8;color:#AD8C08;border:5px double #AD8C08;">
    Enter some text...
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="GetText()"/>
    </form>
    <h2> or </h2>
    <h2> Enter a Text File </h2>
    <input id="inputFileToRead" type="file" onchange="inputFileToRead_Changed(this);">(Path to the Text(*.txt) File)</input>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div id="D3place" align="right">
    <!-- D3 should create svg in this div rather than complete body !-->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

After calculating the frequency from supplied text i am basically creating a object array **Data** which contains letter and frequency as object elements.
The part of javascript code i am using for D3 visualization is:

```
    var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(formatPercent);
    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Number of Occurence:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency*sum + "</span>";
      })
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    svg.call(tip);
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);
   svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency);         })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    }

    function type(d) {
      d.frequency = +d.frequency;
      return d;
    }
```

Comment: Just have a look at where you try to append the SVG. Hint `d3.select("Dplace").append("svg") `.

Comment: You have Dplace in the script, and D3place in the html.

Comment: earlier it was body., i tried to bind it out using        d3.select("Dplace").append("svg") but nothing runs, it works only when i select the body. i've updated the code with the working code